# Changing the time and date in Xcode simulator

Tags: xcode, time, ios-simulator

How to change the time in the iPhone simulator ? I want the other apps on my phone to see a different time than the current one.

Answer (score 16):

Change your system time on the host Mac. The Simulator runs a separate userspace but shares the kernel so it doesn't have a notion of a different time from the host.

Answer (score 7):

Old question, modern answer:

[With Xcode 11, Apple shipped new features for the simctl tool](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_release_notes), which allows you to have a bit more control over what the simulators look like by overriding status bar values.

**Finding the correct device**
The command `xcrun simctl list` [lists the currently installed simulators and gives their status](https://nshipster.com/simctl/):

```
% xcrun simctl list
== Device Types ==
<list of device types>

== Runtimes ==
<list of runtimes>

== Devices ==
-- iOS 13.5 --
    iPhone 11 (A2A694CF-8DA3-4371-AD2D-A2592A5C770C) (Shutdown) 
    iPhone 11 Pro (F36583E8-6833-4526-8622-CE24022BE876) (Booted) 
    iPhone 11 Pro Max (82029941-193B-423E-BE89-DD3E1C0B12E6) (Shutdown)
```

The output of this command is very long so NSHipster was nice enough to provide a command that prints the `UDID` of the currently booted device in [their simctl article](https://nshipster.com/simctl/):

```
$ xcrun simctl list devices | \
    grep "(Booted)"         | \
    grep -E -o -i "([0-9a-f]{8}-([0-9a-f]{4}-){3}[0-9a-f]{12})"
9FED67A2-3D0A-4C9C-88AC-28A9CCA44C60
```

Grab the appropriate device UDID and pass that into the following command to change the simulator's current time:

```
% xcrun simctl status_bar F36583E8-6833-4526-8622-CE24022BE876 override --time "9:41"
%
```

Running `xcrun simctl help status_bar` will show a full range of options:

```
$ xcrun simctl help status_bar
Set or clear status bar overrides
Usage: simctl status_bar <device> [list | clear | override <override arguments>]

Supported Operations:
    list
    List existing overrides.

    clear
    Clear all existing status bar overrides.

    override <override arguments>
    Set status bar override values, according to these flags.
    You may specify any combination of these flags (at least one is required):

    --time <string>
         Set the date or time to a fixed value.
         If the string is a valid ISO date string it will also set the date on relevant devices.
    --dataNetwork <dataNetworkType>
         If specified must be one of 'wifi', '3g', '4g', 'lte', 'lte-a', or 'lte+'.
    --wifiMode <mode>
         If specified must be one of 'searching', 'failed', or 'active'.
    --wifiBars <int>
         If specified must be 0-3.
    --cellularMode <mode>
         If specified must be one of 'notSupported', 'searching', 'failed', or 'active'.
    --cellularBars <int>
         If specified must be 0-4.
    --operatorName <string>
         Set the cellular operator/carrier name. Use '' for the empty string.
    --batteryState <state>
         If specified must be one of 'charging', 'charged', or 'discharging'.
    --batteryLevel <int>
         If specified must be 0-100.
```

Comment: You can specify the device name instead of messing with the UUID, e.g. `xcrun simctl status_bar "iPhone 11 Pro Max" override --time "7:11"`

Comment: For me this only changed the time shown in the status bar, it does not change the system time on the simulator.

Comment: Yeah, I appreciate the effort but this answer is such a waste of time. It doesn't change the simulation system time... just the status bar